# Heading elements appearing below content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I can't position the items correctly:

1 - The titles "App name", "Title 1" and "Title 2" (`h1` tags) are located below the cells and not above.

2- The vertical spaces between the `div` are very large

I tried "playing" using the properties in several elements:

- `align-items`
- `justify-item`
- `align-self`
- `justify-self`
- `margin`
- `padding`

**My code**:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title1""title2""title3";
  background-color: crimson;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

.title1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title1-subtitle1 title1-subtitle2""title1-subtitle3 title1-subtitle4";
  grid-area: title1;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.title1>div {
  background-color: orange;
}

.title1 div>h2,
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title1-subtitle1 {
  grid-area: title1-subtitle1;
}

.title1-subtitle2 {
  grid-area: title1-subtitle2;
}

.title1-subtitle3 {
  grid-area: title1-subtitle3;
}

.title1-subtitle4 {
  grid-area: title1-subtitle4;
}

.title2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title2-subtitle1 title2-subtitle2";
  grid-area: title2;
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.title2>div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.title2 div>h2,
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title2-subtitle1 {
  grid-area: title2-subtitle1;
}

.title2-subtitle2 {
  grid-area: title2-subtitle2;
}

.title3 {
  grid-area: title3;
  background-color: violet;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.title3>h1,
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <h1>App name</h1>
  <div class="title1">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class="title1-subtitle1">
      <h2>Title 1 - Subtitle 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, nihil ducimus pariatur dolore voluptas repellendus et sed, debitis sit tempore nam blanditiis, accusantium aliquam iusto inventore officia aperiam quos repudiandae?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="title1-subtitle2">
      <h2>Title 1 - Subtitle 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, nihil ducimus pariatur dolore voluptas repellendus et sed, debitis sit tempore nam blanditiis, accusantium aliquam iusto inventore officia aperiam quos repudiandae? Lorem ipsum, dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, odit aspernatur ea dolores dicta nisi, unde ut dolorem omnis iste blanditiis saepe, dolorum rerum quos consequuntur temporibus veritatis voluptatum accusantium? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quod qui, incidunt voluptas aperiam corrupti molestiae aut nostrum voluptatem ratione totam dicta, distinctio expedita quaerat magni repellendus aliquid, animi sapiente quo.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="title1-subtitle3">
      <h2>Title 1 - Subtitle 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="title1-subtitle4">
      <h2>Title 1 - Subtitle 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, nihil ducimus pariatur dolore voluptas repellendus et sed, debitis sit tempore nam blanditiis, accusantium aliquam iusto inventore officia aperiam quos repudiandae?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title2">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <div class="title2-subtitle1">
      <h2>Title 2 - Subtitle 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, nihil ducimus pariatur dolore voluptas repellendus et sed, debitis sit tempore nam blanditiis, accusantium aliquam iusto inventore officia aperiam quos repudiandae?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="title2-subtitle2">
      <h2>Title 2 - Subtitle 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, nihil ducimus pariatur dolore voluptas repellendus et sed, debitis sit tempore nam blanditiis, accusantium aliquam iusto inventore officia aperiam quos repudiandae?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title3">
    <h1>Title 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A velit in aperiam, expedita nesciunt nemo ea pariatur explicabo laudantium quasi commodi sed laboriosam obcaecati, libero nobis voluptas? Aliquam, possimus. Nemo.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look like:

[image: Example image]

Comment: I wouldn't use grid. Only with flex would do the job. Try flex-direction: column, then centre headings with: text-align: center to start with.

Comment: I solved the two problems (location of the title and the vertical space) with those properties that you indicated, but now the items (`h2` items) are seen one below the other, and not in X number of rows / columns (this makes sense because I modified the display: grid), I can't think of how to do it only with flex. https://jsfiddle.net/5qa7oxfd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your title placement was that you didn't define a `grid-area` name for them, and then list it in `grid-template-areas`.

Once in a grid container, a heading (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) is just another grid item.

Because it was being ignored by `grid-template-areas` it was handled by the [grid auto-placement algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo), which was rendering it last.

Comment: With what you said I solved the problem of the location of the titles. As a good practice, should `h1` be inside a `div` and should this `div` be part `grid-template-areas` (as I did with `h1-title1`)? Or can I simply use `h1` as a grid item (as I did with `h1-title2`)?
https://jsfiddle.net/Ldx3qy7a/
I solved the problem of vertical spaces by removing `grid-template-rows` and using only `grid-row-gap`.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the `<h1>Title 1</h1>` out of the div element? and while your at it, upload your code to jsfiddle or something, it's very convenient

Comment: If I move `<h1> App name </h1> out of `<div class = "grid-container">`, the tite is seen outside the red cell. If I move `<h1> Title 1 </h1>` out of `<div class = "title1">`, the title is displayed inside the red rectangle instead of inside the yellow rectangle.